# When I tried to connect DB i 'm getting ERROR: This assembly is built by a runtime newer than currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded

Tags: oracle, powershell-2.0, windows-server-2008-r2, odp.net

When I tried to connect DB  from PowerShell in Windows Server 2008 R2. I am getting an error:

> Could not load file or assembly ODP.NET or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.

Command:

```
Add-Type -Path "D:\SelfAnalysisKit\odp.net\ODP.NET_Managed_ODAC122cR1\odp.net\managed\common\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll"
              $DBName = $db_name
              $DBUsername = $user_id
              $DBPassword = $password
              $DBTable = "$name"
              $hostname=$db_name
              $SID=$sid
              $search=$jobid

              $data_source = "(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=$hostname)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER=dedicated)(SERVICE_NAME=$SID)))"

              # -----------------Connect to Oracle------------------------

              $connectionString = 'User Id=' + $DBUsername + ';Password=' + $DBPassword + ';Data Source=' + $data_source
              $connection = New-Object Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection($connectionString)
```

Comment: Can you provide the command you are using to connect

Comment: @JimMacaulay-  command i'm using to connect DB: $connectionString = 'User Id=' + $DBUsername + ';Password=' + $DBPassword + ';Data Source=' + $data_source
              $connection = New-Object Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection($connectionString)

Comment: D:\SelfAnalysisKit\odp.net - This does not look like a directory. Is this a file?

Comment: No ,that is directory.

Comment: D:\SelfAnalysisKit\odp.net\ODP.NET_Managed_ODAC122cR1\odp.net\managed\common\Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll -> This dll file is not available and that's the error you have

Comment: But i can able to connect  DB using this command in powershell version 4, the issue only with powershell version 2.0.

Comment: Then is a compatible issue. May be you existing .Net version is not supported with this functionality

Comment: The message is clear. Dll you're trying to use is built for a higher runtime than the runtime you're using it from. This is it.